# Strange behaviour of merge clause

Tags: c#, winforms

nice people! I am stuck at one problem here and really need your help. I have a Winforms application, which has a few tabs. It connects to MS SQL Server 2008 DB and shows us a DataGridView on the first tab where we 
connect to the DB:

```
private void button_ConnectDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sqlConnection == null || sqlConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    sqlConnection.Open();
    try
    {
        dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryStringUsers, sqlConnection);
        SetConnectDBObjects();
        SetConnectDBButtons();
    }
    catch
    {
        ShowUnableToConnect();
        return;
    }

}
```

and have some info from DB:

```
private void button_SpecAcc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = this.usersBindingSource;
        LoadData(ref dataAdapter, ref clientDataSet, TAB_USERS);
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
    },
```

where **LoadData** is actually:

```
private void LoadData(ref SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter, ref clientDataSet dataset, string table)
    { dataAdapter.Fill(dataset, table); }
```

I have the dataAdapter connected straight to SQL Server, so its configured automatically (all operations, like INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE also). And everything worked just fine (could connect to DB, make any operations, save it (via Apply button, which uses adapter"s **Update** method)), until Ive decided to make another tab.
Another tab should get me the info (several rows) from other place (some ext device I have connected with), get it into DataTable and MERGE with other rows from the DB. Did it all on this tab following this tutorial: [**website**](http://www.jarloo.com/c-bulk-upsert-to-sql-server-tutorial/).

When I try to MERGE some row I can see in my DB nice and good **UPDATE**, BUT in my first tab (on the form) I can see TWO different rows (one, as if it wasn"t touched and second - as if it was updated). I supposed it''s something with Refreshing (tried Refreshing of GridView, didn"t help), or some other element"s Refresh (but which one?...), and I still can not find it. 
Would appreciate any help... Thanks

Comment: Couldn't find it for now, unfortunately.. Forgot to mention, that after I re-run the application, I see just one row, as it's supposed to be. The main problem - is to get one row in runtime situation.

Comment: OR if I look at my first tab AFTER I start program and merge (Start Program, then merge, then connect and look in DB on first tab) it`s also just fine. Only if I connect before merging, I see these phantoms..

Comment: chased id down to adapter.Fill method problem. It adds rows instead of refreshing them. Does someone know, how to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Dealt with it through creating temp dataset, editing it (via DataRows) and getting it into a database. Thanks all the watchers :)